# 200 rep cap is not reached

Tags: bug, status-declined, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

On this [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431931/why-is-s-so-much-faster-than-s-s-in-this-perl-regex/38433055#38433055) the vote count is now at 19 (+21-2). I didn't reach the 200 reputation points cap, but the reputation points don't add up (stuck at 190):

[image]

Others have already encountered that, but it was an issue of Community Post (which is not the case here).

What causes the cap to be 190 and not 200 at it should be?

---

```
-- 2016-07-16 rep +5    = 14245     
 2  38433055 (10)
 2  38433055 (10)
 2  38433055 (10)
 3  38433055 (-2)
 2  38433055 (10)
 2  38435802 (10)
 2  38435802 (10)
 2  38433055 (10)
 2  38433055 (10)
 2  38433055 (10)
 2  38433055 (10)
 2  38433055 (10)
 2  38433055 (10)
 2  38435802 (10)
 2  38437924 (10)
 2  38433055 (10)
 2  38439632 (10)
 2  38439632 (10)
 2  38439632 (10)
 2  38433055 (10)
 2  38433055 (10)
 2  38433055 [2]
 3  38433055 [-2]
 2  38433055 [2]
 2  38433055 [0]
 2  38433055 [0]
 2  38433055 [0]
 2  38433055 [0]
 2  38433055 [0]
 2  38433055 [0]
 2  38433055 [0]
-- 2016-07-18 rep +200  = 14445     

** rep today: 200
** rep this week (2016-07-17 - 2016-07-23): 200
** rep this month (2016-07-01 - 2016-07-31): 567
** rep this quarter (2016-07-01 - 2016-09-30): 567
** rep this year (2016-01-01 - 2016-12-31): 5834
** rep from bonuses: 100
** total rep 14445 :)

days represented 594
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 6 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 9 days
earned 106 reputation from suggested edits
```

Comment: This is indeed strange. For the first time, I thought I'll proceed to your tab and find something like an un-upvote or reversal... but no, neither of them is the case there, looks like a bug.

Comment: What happens when you tick "show removed posts"? Shouldn't change much though.

Comment: @nicael Downvotes won't show up for you, almost certainly not a bug.

Comment: @Servy Nope. In case of ten downvotes, we'd see the rep inflated by 10 points, not reduced. (i.e. 210, not 190)

Comment: @nicael That's if at least 2 of the upvotes were cast after all actions that cost rep.  If they weren't, it'd be 190.

Comment: @Servy No, we would never see the daily rep *reduced* because that user downvoted anything. E.g., if I get an answer upvote and then downvote an answer, you'd see "10" in my rep tab (as I never downvoted), and I'd see "9". So at very minimum, it could be 200, but it isn't.

Comment: @Thomas What do you see for today at the bottom of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation)?

Comment: @nicael nice feature, I wasn't aware of it. See edit

Comment: Huh, then it's most certainly a bug, probably a short-term. You may want to wait till tomorrow, it should be fixed.

Comment: Wait'n'see then. Thanks

Comment: One of the upvotes you got on that 20+ answer didn't register. 20 minutes is way longer than the recalc delay that occurs on user-deletion. And unupvotes don't cause this. wtf...

Comment: How can one get +124 of reputation with upvotes? Shouldn't it be multiple of 10?

Comment: @falsarella I would say it's retracted downvotes

Comment: @fal This is because two of upvotes granted only 2 rep points, since both times Thomas was at 198 (two reps away from rep cap).

Comment: Marked as declined since @nicael's answer makes perfect sense. Just be patient next time. :-)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The reputation tab occasionally glitches due to unknown errors (maybe some post deletions-undeletions, or, as happened to me a couple of times, due to extremely concurrent events).

Since the /reputation displays everything fine and also your reputation *matches the actual one*, the reputation tab must be fixed soon automatically, I'd say tomorrow - there's a script which does a deeper recalc and runs periodically at night - either at 0:00 UTC or 3:00 UTC, can't say for sure (haven't tracked).

---

Now it's fixed indeed :) Showing 200 reps for yesterday.

Comment: The nightly script does not recalculate all reputation histories every night. Reputation recalcs get *scheduled* when some event happens that warrants a recalc (mainly delete/undelete events), and then the recalc occurs the next time the script runs (on ~15 intervals).

Comment: @ani Thanks.  What do you mean by *~15  intervals*?

Comment: @nicael ~15 *minute* intervals. Every 15 minutes, the script to run scheduled recalculations is activated.